# Enable Firebase Authentication via API or SDK

Tags: api, firebase-authentication

As part of my project, I need to enable the firebase authentication from API or SDK.
I didn't found any solution - the only way is to enable it from the console.

Is anyone familiar with that?

[image: Enable Autentication]

EDIT: I finally found the solution for enabling GCP service.
The following link explains how to enable GCP services via REST: https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/enable-disable

Comment: What is is your exact problem? Here is not a forum. Ask your question in clear way and be specific please

Comment: To enable providers, this is the best I can think of: https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.defaultSupportedIdpConfigs

Comment: I need to enable the authentication method programmatically. - I added a pic from the firebase UI. So instead of pressing the "Get Started" button from the UI - I need to enable it from API or SDK.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - thanks, but I need to enable the signIn method so it seems not to be the way for me.

Comment: @Kazavo Did you find a way to enable the authentication method programmatically eventually?

Answer (score 2):

After my long search I found the way:
The serviceusage Google API provides a REST API for enabling/disabling GCP service. PLease note that after the service enabled, it needed to enable the signIn method. You can see examples from my code below.

**Service Enabling:**

```
 url = 
'https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{IDENTIFIER:}/services:batchEnable'.format(IDENTIFIER=project_idetifier)
  if verbose: print(bcolors.INFO + 'GET URL: {url:}'.format(url=url) + bcolors.ENDC)
  headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {token:}'.format(token=access_token),\
    'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  payload = {
    "serviceIds": ["identitytoolkit"],
  }
  r = httpReq.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
  resp_body = json.loads(r.text)
```

**Enable SignIn Method:**

```
  url = 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/admin/v2/projects/{project_id:}/config?updateMask=signIn.email.enabled,signIn.email.passwordRequired'.format(project_id=project_id)
  headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {token:}'.format(token=access_token),\
    'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  payload = {"signIn": {"email": {"enabled": True, "passwordRequired": True}}}
  r = httpReq.patch(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
  resp_body = json.loads(r.text)
```

Just a note: The access token was generated from the service account JSON file:

```
  credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
          <YOUR_JSON_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PATH>, scopes=CREDENTIAL_SCOPES)
  credentials.refresh(requests.Request())
  return credentials.token
```

Comment: Not working for me, getting an error `no config available` on the second step when trying to enable auth method. If open firebase auth through UI before second step - it starts working so I believe we need one more step here to emulate what firebase UI is doing when we are opening it for the first time.

Comment: @AliakseiStadnik Same for me. Did you find a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Endpoint [https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/{project=projects/*}/identityPlatform:initializeAuth](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/%7Bproject=projects/*%7D/identityPlatform:initializeAuth)

this will initialize identity and create auth

[take a look here](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.identityPlatform/initializeAuth)